# How to connect android device with bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am trying to connect with android device with Bluetooth but i couldn't conntect

I have simple code below

```
BluetoothAdapter adapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
```

But i got the result `adapter=null` and  Bluetooth NOT supported. Aborting.

How to connect bluetooth through the emulator?
Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a physical device, you can't use BT on the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to connect to the bluetooth using the emulator. If your PC has bluetooth feature,you can connect to an Android device using your app.

Comment: how to add a bluetooth feature in pc can you explain me?

Comment: Hahaha,i am not talking about that.Here By "PC",i mean laptop or something.Most of the laptops these days have bluetooth feature.